# Deploying Adapter on Bluemix-MobileFirst Foundation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, mobilefirst-adapters, ibm-mobile-services

I have registered on IBM Bluemix. I've created a Mobile Foundation Service.

Now I wanted to deploy a JavaAdapter on bluemix-MobileFoundation. But getting some "**FWLSE0321**: state change Failure...exception" during deployment.
The adapter deployed successfully in my machine with local MobileFirst Server 8.0.

For locally installed server - POM.xml

```
   <mfpfUrl>http://localhost:9080/mfpadmin</mfpfUrl>
```

so my question is, If I want to deploy Adapter **on Bluemix-Mobilefoundation** then,

> 1. what would be the **"mfpUrl"** ? and
> 2. In mfp Operation Console, from where I'll get this URL?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open your MFP service from your dashboard, the name of the server will appear on the opened service's main overview page. It would be of the format

```
<server-name>.mybluemix.net
```

This will be your **mfpfURL** along with **https://** and the server url must be followed by the port number ( the default is 443). Viz :

```
<mfpfUrl>https://<server-name>.mybluemix.net:443/mfpadmin</mfpfUrl>
```

And when the operations console is opened, the url of the opened page will consist your server url too.

Comment: Found it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can get the URL from the MobileFirst Console. Make sure you use https and port 443

[image]

Comment: Got it. Thank you.